# \textit and \textbf commands are not working

Tags: fonts, formatting

It doesn't show any error, but the italics/ bold text doesn't appear. I saw similar previously answered questions, and it was often due to package incompatibility. I am a new user and do not know what to do.
Here's the template document I am facing the error

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1.75in,noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec, color, enumerate, sectsty}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                      YOUR INFORMATION
%
%      PLEASE EDIT THE FOLLOWING LINES ACCORDINGLY!!
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\soptitle}{Statement of Purpose}
\newcommand{\yourname}{firstname lastname}
\newcommand{\youremail}{email@address.edu}

%% FONTS SETUP
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Path = fonts/, Ligatures={Common}]{adobe_caslon_pro}
\setmonofont[Path = fonts/, Scale=0.8]{monaco}
\setsansfont[Path = fonts/, Scale=0.9]{Optima-Regular}
\newcommand{\amper}{{\fontspec[Scale=.95]{Adobe Caslon Pro}\selectfont\itshape\&~{}}}
\usepackage[bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks,
pdftitle={\yourname - \soptitle},pdfauthor={\yourname}, unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=magneta,citecolor=magenta,filecolor=magenta,urlcolor=[named]{WildStrawberry}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                      Title and Author Name
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{center}{\huge \scshape \soptitle}\end{center}
\begin{center}\vspace{0.2em} {\Large \yourname\\}
  {\youremail}\end{center}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                      SOP Body
% NOTE: Use \amper instead of \&
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam
sodales, ipsum a commodo tempus, arcu magna bibendum turpis, at
eleifend nulla lectus et turpis. Etiam nisi risus, ultricies at auctor
id, mollis vitae lorem. Morbi vel rhoncus mi. Aenean euismod eros
vitae turpis porttitor varius. Donec aliquam fringilla tellus nec
venenatis. Fusce ornare tempor metus, non bibendum massa vehicula sit
amet. Integer ultrices rutrum velit, in facilisis augue feugiat sed.
Fusce luctus tristique pretium. Nullam consequat tincidunt sem, at
gravida purus gravida at. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc ante leo, volutpat
pretium fringilla id, malesuada et dolor. Aliquam blandit, magna eget
porta tempus, quam neque ultrices mi, vel pretium ipsum ante tristique
massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

\section*{Research Experience}
\paragraph{Project \#1}
Morbi sed sapien ut ante elementum luctus vitae et libero. Praesent
felis enim, elementum nec suscipit non, suscipit a diam. Nulla
vulputate facilisis orci, vel iaculis odio feugiat id. Fusce in dolor
interdum ante dignissim bibendum. Nullam euismod interdum commodo.
Etiam a mauris ac purus dignissim ultrices at eu nisl. Suspendisse
varius ipsum eu massa ullamcorper in convallis nulla vulputate.

\paragraph{Project \#2}
Nam facilisis lacinia gravida. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent
fermentum, est vitae ultrices vulputate, sapien leo hendrerit elit,
sed lacinia enim tortor scelerisque augue. Aliquam non sapien metus,
sed tincidunt dolor. Sed porta euismod pharetra. Aenean augue urna,
sollicitudin at viverra quis, ullamcorper ac quam. Pellentesque est
ante, tincidunt sed mollis nec, posuere sit amet risus. Aenean ut
tortor dolor. Curabitur at odio at quam lacinia malesuada vitae vel
ante. Morbi nisl nisi, elementum non porta non, auctor vitae tellus.
Pellentesque quis eleifend lectus. Duis sit amet orci massa, at luctus
lectus. Aenean sit amet nulla erat. Duis egestas tristique dignissim.
Nam iaculis massa eu felis rhoncus gravida.

\paragraph{Project \#3}
Nulla non mauris quis mi pellentesque interdum. Sed venenatis pretium
sem sed pretium. Pellentesque et augue velit, ut bibendum leo. Proin
congue nisl id leo tristique sagittis. Curabitur id diam in turpis
faucibus pharetra eget elementum orci. Sed vel nunc nibh. Praesent non
enim eros, sed convallis dui. Pellentesque accumsan viverra dolor sed
luctus.

\paragraph{Project \#4}
Sed non posuere leo. Curabitur eu est ut tellus ultrices ornare quis
ut tortor. Aliquam faucibus mauris in leo tincidunt euismod. Aliquam
lacinia euismod dolor, tempus gravida erat facilisis elementum.
Pellentesque pretium pharetra orci, eu consequat arcu dapibus et.
Quisque quis dolor magna. Fusce gravida risus at ipsum lobortis id
facilisis justo malesuada. Donec egestas placerat congue. Curabitur
eget diam at odio iaculis pellentesque quis in est. Aenean sit amet
sodales tortor. Morbi a nulla magna.

\section*{Education}
Cras facilisis tristique nisi, eu vestibulum dolor molestie vel. Nam
bibendum consectetur risus, a sodales odio commodo aliquam. Proin et
nibh non felis ultrices ornare nec vel dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mi ante, condimentum a rhoncus
non, tristique at sapien. Donec ultricies urna sit amet lectus ornare
ut feugiat mauris pharetra. Quisque blandit purus a nisi scelerisque
imperdiet. Nunc accumsan accumsan mauris quis fermentum. Suspendisse
vitae pellentesque nibh. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Phasellus suscipit diam non est accumsan non suscipit
mi mattis. Aliquam bibendum quam id lacus venenatis in interdum orci
congue. Sed nunc augue, blandit semper ornare vitae, consequat vitae
velit. Aliquam lacus massa, imperdiet malesuada scelerisque lacinia,
vehicula et est. Mauris imperdiet, mi vel hendrerit lobortis, magna
odio semper diam, sed bibendum arcu velit in nisl. Morbi viverra
varius orci.

Praesent vel mi pharetra justo lacinia consectetur. In in odio neque.
Donec in tellus nulla, quis fringilla quam. In hac habitasse platea
dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas nisi elit, dictum
at fringilla vitae, vestibulum vitae ligula. Vestibulum ante ipsum
primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis
placerat ipsum sit amet ante fermentum condimentum. Nunc facilisis
eros euismod nisl euismod id egestas turpis imperdiet. Etiam
consectetur risus vitae augue scelerisque in fringilla odio
vestibulum. Ut venenatis convallis suscipit. Maecenas cursus dignissim
semper. Vestibulum tempor lectus vel justo consequat vel faucibus enim
viverra. Donec nunc ligula, luctus nec molestie eget, aliquam vel
lectus.

\section*{Teaching Experience}
Praesent quam lectus, porttitor vel placerat non, tincidunt ac eros.
Sed vitae libero risus, nec auctor ante. Aenean dapibus est blandit
lorem facilisis nec blandit justo semper. Duis at sapien ante, vitae
pulvinar urna. Mauris a nisi purus. Sed scelerisque, ligula eget
scelerisque dignissim, quam massa luctus est, vel rhoncus augue dolor
sed lacus. Vestibulum ultricies, metus a condimentum elementum, nisl
turpis ultricies massa, in pulvinar neque quam vitae erat. Etiam
consequat, massa a elementum bibendum, nisi eros porta nisl, pretium
interdum dolor enim a tortor. Mauris ante tortor, consectetur quis
tristique ac, ultricies et mauris. Integer turpis sapien, tincidunt
vitae hendrerit iaculis, malesuada tincidunt mi. Aliquam sollicitudin
sem vestibulum felis tincidunt hendrerit. Praesent leo turpis,
tincidunt quis rhoncus quis, hendrerit at nibh. Mauris congue interdum
viverra. Donec ut est nunc, non feugiat diam.

Mauris vestibulum elit et eros adipiscing luctus. Aenean dignissim
tortor eget mi molestie faucibus. Mauris vel risus non quam viverra
faucibus. Phasellus nibh eros, consequat id aliquam vel, gravida at
nunc. Maecenas nec sem id libero consequat molestie. Ut dictum
ultrices ligula, in tincidunt felis faucibus vitae. Maecenas suscipit
magna nec velit sodales sit amet ullamcorper sem pretium.

\section*{Concluding Remarks}
Etiam id leo eget leo adipiscing sodales vitae faucibus eros. Ut nec
diam nisi. Nunc eu velit orci. Praesent in ligula non lorem facilisis
volutpat pharetra auctor nisi. Curabitur aliquam lacinia orci vel
aliquam. Nullam et massa purus. Quisque sed ipsum nec purus blandit
rhoncus.
\end{document}
```

Comment: First of please complete your example such that it does not give errors when compiled (`\end{document}` is missing). Additional, please specify which engine you're using (xelatex or lualatex). Thirdly are the fonts actually named like that in a subfolder called `fonts`?

Comment: Hello
Thanks for answering. I don't know the answer to your questions. I just went to overleaf and got a template after searching 'Statement of purpose', and I used one. And got stuck with italicising.

Comment: the log will show which fonts fontspec found or did not find. Did you upload a bold font for Caslon  in to your project?

Comment: do you really have to use a template using commercial fonts that you need to buy?